# Divide items that belongs to two query sets in django

Tags: django

I have created two queries in django. One that returns number of handled calls per agent and a second one that returns the missed calls per agents.

I would like to know how to combine the two queries in order to get a percentage of handled calls par agent, which means take the total from the query3 and divide it on the total of query2 grouped by agent. Of course I will render the result to the web page,

Here are the two queries

Thanks

```
# A query that returns total calls that has been handled 
queryset2 = CsqAgentReport.objects.values('agentname').filter(Q(originatordnhandeled__contains='1') | Q(missedcallshandeledy_n__contains='1')).exclude(agentname__contains='None').annotate(total=Count('nodeid_sessionid_sequenceno', distinct=True)).order_by('agentname')

# A query that returns total calls that has been missed  
queryset3 = CsqAgentReport.objects.values('agentname').filter(originatordnnothandeled__contains='1').filter(ringtime__gt = '00:00:00').exclude(agentname__contains='None').annotate(total=Count('nodeid_sessionid_sequenceno', distinct=True)).order_by('agentname')
```

I already developed a script in Python that returns the expected result and I'm looking for something simple and similar in Django see code in Python here below:

```
print ("Nb of handled calls per agent" )
       
cursor.execute(""" SELECT  "AgentName", count (*) FROM "CSQ Agent Report" WHERE  "AgentName" != "None"  AND "OriginatorDNHANDELED" = '1' or "OriginatorDNNOTHANDELED" = '1' Group by "AgentName"  """)
liste8= cursor.fetchall()

for i in range (len(liste8)):
    
    print (liste8[i][0],liste8[i][1])

print ('Nb of missed calls  ')

cursor.execute(""" SELECT  "AgentName", count (*) FROM "CSQ Agent Report" WHERE  "AgentName" != "None"  AND "TalkTime" > '00:00:00' AND "OriginatorDNHANDELED" = '1' OR "MISSEDCALLSHANDELEDY-N" = '1' Group by "AgentName"  """)

liste7= cursor.fetchall()
for i in range (len(liste7)):
    
    print (liste7[i][0],liste7[i][1])


print ('percantage of handled calls per agent  ')
for i in range (len(liste8)):
    
    x = liste8[i][1] 
    y = liste7[i][1]
    d= y / x
    print (liste8[i][0],'{:.0%}'.format(d))
```

Comment: Please share the relevant models. Does the `CsqAgentReport` has a `ForeignKey` to the agent object? This is (normally) better modeling.

Comment: I would strongly advise to make use of an extra model for each `Agent` (and use a `ForeignKey` to that model). This avoids data duplication (which is an anit-pattern), and furthermore makes ORM queries more convenient.

Answer (score 1):

You can work with:

```
from django.db.models import Count, Q

# since Django-2.0

CsqAgentReport.objects.exclude(
    agentname__contains='None'
).values('agentname').filter(
    Q(originatordnnothandeled__contains='1') | Q(missedcallshandeledy_n__contains='1')
).annotate(
   total=Count(
       'nodeid_sessionid_sequenceno',
       distinct=True,
       filter=Q(originatordnnothandeled__contains='1', ringtime__gt = '00:00:00')
   ) / Count('nodeid_sessionid_sequenceno', distinct=True)
)
```

But the modeling itself looks quite *dangerous*. You specify nearly everything as a `TextField`, even fields that contain quantitative data like a duration that is better stored as a [**`DurationField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DurationField), or booleans that should be stored with a [**`BooleanField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.BooleanField).

Filtering like `agentname__contains='None'` is not only inefficient, but also dangerous, since later an agent could have a name `'None'`. It also results in queries with [*primitive obsession* [refactoring.guru]](https://refactoring.guru/smells/primitive-obsession). Normally one better uses a [**`ForeignKey`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey) to refer to an extra model. This means we can *annotate* the `Agent` model which is not only simpler, but also does not erode the model layer.

Comment: Hello , thanks for your reply and advises . I will review the model as per your advise  . The results are not displayed in percentage . How can i fix this ? . .

Comment: @walid: a database is not meant for formatting. A database is used to store, retrieve and aggregate data. The formatting in percentages should be done at the Django/Python level.